# (Android Kotlin) RecyclerView Adapter methods not called: empty RecyclerView being shown

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I am trying to display JSON data from a dummy server (json-server) using Retrofit2 and display it in a RecyclerView placed inside a fragment. So far the following events are taking place (found out using Log infos):

1. Main fragment `CharactersListFragment.kt`  creation is initiated.
2. Only `getItemCount()` is being called. It is returning 0.
3. `OnCreateViewHolder()` and `onBindViewHolder()` are not being called.
4. Data is successfully fetched from the server and passed to the adapter (from `CharactersListFragment.kt`)

There are no compile time errors nor does my app crash, just the RecyclerView is empty.

Here are my code files:

1. Layout for fragment with RecyclerView: `fragment_characters_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".CharactersListFragment">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"

        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

2. Layout for RecyclerView row: `fragment_character_recyclerview_list.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/character_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/violet_forcard"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/char_thumnail_img"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.106"
            tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/char_id_txt"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Character ID: "
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/char_thumnail_img"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/char_name_txt"
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="53dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:text="Name: "
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/char_thumnail_img"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/char_id_txt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/char_descp_txt"
            android:layout_width="359dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
            android:textAlignment="viewStart"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.461"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.918" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

3. Kotlin class for fragment: `CharactersListFragment.kt`

```
package com.example.marvelapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class CharactersListFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var charsAdapter: CharacterListAdapter
    private lateinit var apiService: APIService
    private var characters: MutableList<Character> = ArrayList()


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        Log.i("INSIDE_FRAGMENT_ONCREATEVIEW", "Fragment creation initiated")
        val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_characters_list, container, false)

        apiService = RestClient.client.create(APIService::class.java)

        getCharacterList()

        val recycler_view = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view) as RecyclerView
        recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        charsAdapter = CharacterListAdapter()
        recycler_view.adapter = charsAdapter

        return v
    }

    private fun getCharacterList(){
        val call = apiService!!.get_characters()
        call.enqueue(object: Callback<List<Character>> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Character>>,
                response: Response<List<Character>>
            ) {
                val chars = response.body()
                Log.i("get_character_succeeded_FOR_CALL", chars.toString())
                if (chars != null){
                    characters.addAll(chars!!)
                    Log.i("character_ADD_CHECK_INSIDE_FRAGMENT", characters[0].toString())
                    charsAdapter.submitDataforcharList(characters)
                }

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Character>>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("get_character_failed", t.localizedMessage)
            }

        })
    }

}
```

4. Kotlin class for adapter: `CharacterListAdapter.kt`

```
package com.example.marvelapp

import android.text.Layout
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_character_recyclerview_list.view.*

class CharacterListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    private var charItems: List<Character> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        Log.i("INSIDE_ONCREATE_VIEWHOLDER", "reached")
        return CharacterListViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_character_recyclerview_list,
        parent,
        false))
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when(holder){
            is CharacterListViewHolder ->{
                Log.i("VIEWHOLDER_FOUND", "proceeding to bind")
                holder.bind(charItems.get(position))
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        Log.i("INSIDE_ADAPTER_GET_ITEM_COUNT", charItems.size.toString())
        return charItems.size
    }

    fun submitDataforcharList (characterlist: List<Character>){
        Log.i("INSIDE_ADAPTER_SUBMIT_DATA", characterlist[0].toString())
        charItems = characterlist
    }

    class CharacterListViewHolder
    constructor(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        val char_id = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.char_id_txt)
        val char_name = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.char_name_txt)
        val char_descp = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.char_descp_txt)

        fun bind(character: Character){
            Log.i("INSIDE_VIEWHOLDER_BIND", character.toString())
            val id = Integer.toString(character.charId)
            val id_mess = "Character ID: $id"
            char_id.setText(id_mess)
            val char_name_mess = "Name: ${character.charName}"
            char_name.setText(char_name_mess)
            char_descp.setText(character.charDescp)
        }

    }
}
```

5. the `Character` model class:

```
package com.example.marvelapp


data class Character(
    val charId: Int,
    val charName: String,
    val charDescp: String,
){
}
```

I am an android beginner and have been stuck at this for quite some time, any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the `onCreateView` of `CharactersListFragment` you are doing `getCharacterList()`. So from my understanding of android, this is not an inline call correct? I mean this method call will not block the main thread right? I think you should initialize your adapter class after you have received the data.

Comment: You need to use `charItems.addAll(characterlist)` instead of `charItems = characterlist` . Also you need to call `notifyDatasetChanged()` after it .

Comment: Currently you might be getting some data and you are simply updating the data list in your adapter class but you are not informing your recyclerview to refresh the view to display the new data. So I think if you just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after setting the new data it should work. But I would still suggest initializing the recyclerview after you've received the data from the `getCharacterList()` call.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone, turns out I had to reorder the calling of ```getCharacterList()``` and add the ```notifyDatasetChanged()```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onCreateView` of `CharactersListFragment` you are calling `getCharacterList()` and then you move on with your initialization of the recycler view. After the `getCharacterList` call completes, you might be getting some data and you are simply updating the data list in your adapter class but you are not informing your recyclerview to refresh the view to display the new data. So I think if you just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter after setting the new data it should work.

The other way to solve the issue could be if you initialize your recyclerview after you've received the data from the `getCharacterList()` call and just show some loading icon in place of the recycler view while the data is being fetched.

Answer (score 0):

`getCharacterList()` is called on UI thread (main thread) but communicating (requests and responses) between device and API server is happening in another thread, it means there is no guarantee that `onResponse()` will come earlier than `recycler_view.adapter = charsAdapter` and in reality, it mostly does not happens. Therefor, you must call `charsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after `charsAdapter.submitDataforcharList(characters)` to have the recyclerview represent data. Another more elegent way to do that is adding `notifyDatasetChanged()` inside `submitDataforcharList()`:

```
fun submitDataforcharList (characterlist: List<Character>){
        charItems = characterlist
        notifyDatasetChanged()
}
```

Comment: I added the ```notifyDatasetChanged()``` function as per your answer but then the app crashed with a ```java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0``` so I moved the call for ```submitDataforcharList()``` inside the ```getCharList()``` method and then it worked.

Comment: @SimranSaha the crash is caused by you access element at index 0 of an empty list. Removing `Log.i("INSIDE_ADAPTER_SUBMIT_DATA", characterlist[0].toString())` inside    `submitDataforcharList()` solves the problem.